# Which .NET test frameworks/runners support attaching files (such as a screenshot) to the test report?

Tags: test-automation-framework, browser-automation, mstest, dot-net, tfs

I want to attach an HTML document to any test case that is about to fail. I can do this if I use [Gallio](https://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/) test runner, but it doesn't integrate well with Visual Studio or [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server).

According to Microsoft's documentation I can attach files to a manual test case, but they have nothing for automated tests.

Answer (score 1):

**Microsoft Test Manager (MTM)** supports attachments and it is integrated with Team Foundation Server (TFS). While you executing the test cases you can add screenshots or files to the failed steps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of code you can use to do what you want:
http://vivekbansod.blogspot.com/2013/06/add-attachment-to-test-case-result.html

Comment: I'm guessing this requires a connection to the TFS so it wouldn't work with a local test. I will have to wait for our build team to finish setting up the CI environment before I can try this.

Comment: Practically anything you do with the MS testing framework is going to need a connection to the TFS server. In the interim you can set your tests to email you the HTML, and manually attach the files to the test cases, but you don't want to be doing that for any length of time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using MSTest, and if that's the case you can use `TestContext.AddResultFile()` ([MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.addresultfile.aspx)).  This won't attach files to the test case work item though, it'll only attach files to the test execution result.

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend to look at **[Allure Test Report](http://allure.qatools.ru)** framework, 
it allows attaching screenshots & files (during execution & on failure, as you need).

> Few useful links, as follows:
>
> - [Allure C# library](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp-commons/wiki)
> - [Getting started guide](http://ilya-murzinov.github.io/articles/allure-csharp/)